# intellij System.getProperty ("user.dir"), how to get consistent result , whether ide, run script/app, or test?

Tags: intellij-idea, environment-variables, run-script

Had a bit of a nightmare getting consistent result from my code when reading "user.dir" property depending on how the code was launched.

I have a gradle project, some code & scripts in src/main/groovy and tests in source/test/groovy, and running code from command line, or in the IDE (run script directly) and running some tests

i'd built myself a new gradle project and was trying to open a file resources in src/main/resources.

when i ran my unit tests, the user.dir = 'project root' (which is what i was expecting). when i built a script and right clicked in the IDE, then the user.dir property returned the current script directory path in source main!

so a lookup in a test returned a different test.

I also tried setting this in build.gradle

```
//setup proj.dir as project root
System.setProperty( "proj.dir", project.projectDir.toString() )
```

and build a gradle task to print this - and it shows the project directory as result.

There doesn't appear to a global 'fix or config' in intellij to always get consistent return when reading the property "user.dir" to be project root. unless i missed something?

in the IDE if i look at the run/debug configurations - under defaults the entry for groovy says the working directory is the project root (as id expected).  however when i looked under the groovy node and my script there ('testPCE'), then the working directory was set as the scripts current location.

once i found out that i can edit the IDE run/debug configurations i reset the working directory to be the project root, and now get a consistent result.  But seem to have to check this on each script if i need to.

so my questions is what can i do/configure/set so that i get an env variable which **always** returns the project root, whether from command line launch, in gradle, by running by right click of script from IDE, or from tests in the IDE/ or from commnd line

There must, be a '**robust**' way to ensure that all lookups on some env variable will return the same answer  regardless of how your code is executed.

know i know whats happening, i can adjust my ide to  set where i want working directory to be - but have to keep checking.  I want something reliable that will always work, whether its IDE, command line, inside tomcat web container etc to get the 'project root' and build paths reliably from this one stable point, that will work consistently

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: PS just added a new script in IDE, and ran it.  The IDE automatically set the script 'working directory' to be the script directory, so user.dir returns the script folder.  However if a create a groovy class in the same folder , it defaults the 'working directory' to the project directory.  So its logic in the IDE thats deciding what 'working directory' based on type of artefact being created

Answer (score 0):

perhaps not ideal bu this is working.  I'm trying to load a config file from the resources area that's in the classpath, but my code is a static block in class.

in this case i had to get the classLoader for the Class object and getResource on that (which includes checking across the classpath (i didnt want a spring dependency for this project if i could avoid it).

So the the code that seems to work - without having to resolve "user.dir" property is shown below

```
//configure standard converters
static {
    // class class loader will include resources so file will be found
    def configFile =  "config/BinderConfig.groovy"
    def resource = new File (configFile).canonicalPath
    resource = Gbinder.getClassLoader().getResource(configFile)
    def binderConfig = new ConfigSlurper().parse (resource)

    binderConfig.global.converters.each {
    typeConverters << it
    }

    typeConverters
 }
```